# Flash CS5 As3 Flvplayback 2.5, why some Video only play audio?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, web, flash-cs5

I use Flsh CS5 AS3 Flvplayback 2.5.

The firs question is: I have 9 buttons in the same page with Flvplayback 2.5, when the video is playing and if my mouse rest over the any botton,  didn't click anything, but the video will stop, then if my mouse move away, it will start play again. I don't want because the button break up the videos. Same Flvplayback buttons.
I see the out put : in in in in in in in in, and if I clike onece, I will see: 2_Nat Geo Clips_Red Wolf Docu was clicked.
How do I fix that????

Thanks for your time to help me! I wish you have a great sunny day!

```
  import fl.video.*;
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;
  var flvPlayer:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
  addChild(flvPlayer);
  flash.events.Event.MOUSE_LEAVE
   //The next line assumes you have copied the skin file to the directory
   //that contains the published SWF file. If you are testing the 
   //application in Flash Professional, this is the same directory as the
   //FLA file, too.
   if (! myVideo.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT))
   {
videoMask.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, __onIn);
videoMask.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, __onOut);

function __onIn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    trace("in");
    if (! myVideo.playing)
    {
        myVideo.play();

    }
}

function __onOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (myVideo.playing)
    {
        myVideo.pause();

    }
}
}

var mybtn:Array = new Array       (Movie1_btn,Movie2_btn,Movie3_btn,Movie4_btn,Movie5_btn,Movie6_btn,Movie7_btn,Movie8_btn,Movie9_btn);
for (var i=0; i<mybtn.length; i++)
 {
mybtn[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler);
function clickhandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    if (event.target == Movie1_btn)
    {
        myVideo.source = "1_Bad Water Sequence.mov";
    }
    else if (event.target==Movie2_btn)
    {
        myVideo.source = "2_Nat Geo Clips_Red Wolf Docu.mp4";
    }
    else if (event.target==Movie3_btn)
    {
        myVideo.source = "3_News_Anthrax_Postal Story.mov";
    }
    else if (event.target==Movie4_btn)
    {
        myVideo.source = "4_Energy Ducumentary 2 min Clip.mov";
    }
    else if (event.target==Movie5_btn)
    {
        myVideo.source = "5_Wildlife_Scenic_Reel.mov";
    }
    else if (event.target==Movie6_btn)
    {
        myVideo.source = "6_Intro Title Sequence for Mt.Rushmore Webcasts.mov";
    }
    else if (event.target==Movie7_btn)
    {
        myVideo.source = "7_PowWow Ancestry Dream Sequence.mov";
    }
    else if (event.target==Movie8_btn)
    {
        myVideo.source = "8_Fence Fixin-Western style-L.mov";
    }
    else if (event.target==Movie9_btn)
    {
        myVideo.source = "9_Docu_3 separate Clips.mov";
    }
}
 }

 function readyHandler(event:VideoEvent):void
 {
  // Pause until the video can play till the end
 myVideo.pause();
 myVideo.playWhenEnoughDownloaded();
}

 myVideo.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, readyHandler);

stop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Mouse Over with MouseEvent.CLICK, be sure that there is a background for button

Comment: MOUSE_OVER replay MouseEvent.CLICK??? What background are you talking about it? Is in the btn_button or on the stage?

Comment: Can I take that MOUSE_OVER OUT??? lIKE THIS:If (! myVideo.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT))
{
 videoMask.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, __onOut);

 function __onOut(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  trace("out");
  if (! myVideo.playing)
  {
   myVideo.play();
   
  }
 }
}

Comment: I try this way, but when I leave the page, the video sound still play in that background, What should I do? If I replace the MOUSE_OVER then I have this 1119:Access of possibly undefined property MouseEvent through a reference with static type class.  Here is the code: if (! myVideo.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT))
{
 videoMask.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, __onOut);

 function __onOut(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  trace("out");
  if (! myVideo.playing)
  {
   myVideo.play();
   
  }
 }
}